# Handle errors in Angular UI Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

On server side i have a next method, which check if token found in database:

```
def method(token) 
   if (Database.find(token).length == 0)
     not_found()
   else
     success()
end
```

url as `token/:token`, for example `token/123`

I have a state for it:

```
   $stateProvider.state('token', {
     url: '/token/:token',
     templateUrl: 'success'
   }).state('404', {
      url: '/404',
      templateUrl: 'notfound'
   });
```

But i do not know, how to in ui router check token, i need some like this

```
$http.post('/token', {token: $stateParams.token}).success(function(){  
     //ok continue and load `success` template
}).error(function(){
    $state.go('404'); //when error
});
```

Is it possible with ui router?

Comment: I think you can handle it via resolve method in ui-router, So return false promise based on your condition.

Comment: How to use it for in my case?

Comment: Can you please explain more in question about what kind of your token is it used for authentication or something else. what is the purpose of  checking the token before routing.

Comment: token is only number. It might be used for activate account, for example if token exist, i should display info that account activated, otherwise (when token not valid or not found), i should redirect to 404, now it -> display success page and check if exist and then if token not valid -> 404, but i want do it before display success page.

Comment: Ok, that what I did in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same situation, This is what I did

```
.when('/beacon/:beacon_id',{
        templateUrl : 'components/beacon/beacon.html',
        controller : 'beaconController',
        access : { requiredLogin: true },
        resolve : {
            Beacon : ['$route', 'BeaconService', function($route, BeaconService){
                var beacon = BeaconService.beacon();
                return beacon.get({'beacon_id':$route.current.params.beacon_id}, function(successResponse){
                    console.log(successResponse.result[0]);
                    return successResponse.result[0];
                }, function(errorResponse){
                    $location.path('blablabla'); // This will redirect me to 404. :P
                });
            }] 
        }
    })
.otherwise({templateUrl : '404.html'});
```

In controller

```
App.controller('beaconCtrl', ['Beacon', '$scope', function(Beacon, $scope){
    //Get Beacon into controller than get your promise.
    Beacon.$promise.then(function(data){
        $scope.beacon = data.result[0];
    });
}]);
```